# Selenium Python 3.4.3 Loging into Gmail: Password section

Tags: python, selenium

So below is my code so far. It is supposed to go to the website and login with all the necessary details but i keep on getting huge chunks of errors! I dont understand where the error is hiding, anyone who sees it please help. Thanks!

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#browser.get('https://mail.yahoo.com')
browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&scc=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=en&service=mail#identifier')

emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys('email_address')
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
passwordElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
passwordElem.clear()
passwordElem.send_keys('12345')

SignIn = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
SignIn.click()

#passwordElem.clear()
#passwordElem.send_keys('12345')
#SignIn = browser.find_elements_by_id('signIn')
#SignIn.click()
#passwordElem.submit()
```

This is the error i am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp-450/Desktop/Automating_Gmail.py", line 15, in <module>
    passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/hp-450/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3awlgy5b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///C:/Users/hp-450/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3awlgy5b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/hp-450/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3awlgy5b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/hp-450/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3awlgy5b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/hp-450/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp3awlgy5b/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: Slayer, can you please clarify. What do you mean by "ad the error you have."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you enter your email and submit the form, [wait for the password field to be visible](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# wait for the password field to be visible
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
passwordElem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Passwd")))
passwordElem.clear()
passwordElem.send_keys('12345')

SignIn = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
SignIn.click()
```

Also note that you have to use `find_element_by_id()` instead of the `find_elements_by_id()` method to locate the "Sign In" button.

Comment: Hey Alecxe, thanks for the suggestion but there is still an error that is coming and i forgot to mention that i have already tried doing something similar.

Comment: @stuum1. well, I actually tested that and it works on my end.

Comment: @n1c9 , The error i am receiving is too long to put here as a comment.

Comment: @stuum1. edit the question and post it there. Thanks.

Comment: @stuum1. now you need to remove the `browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')` line of course - you are using wait instead.